# How to add multiple pages in Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm a beginner on GAE and I was wondering if it was possible to add another page to it so  the home page would be

"example.appspot.com"

and the second would be

"example.appspot.com/test"

I've already tried looking for something that helps but the answers aren't what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course it is possible to add more pages.  The configuration for defining the URL matchers depends on the language runtime that you are using.

For Java:

> The deployment descriptor is a file named web.xml. It resides in the
>   app's WAR under the WEB-INF/ directory.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/webxml

For Python:

> A Python app specifies runtime configuration, including versions and
>   URLs, in a file named app.yaml

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Python_app_yaml_About_app_yaml

Comment: This isn't a scalable approach if you have  hundreds or thousands of pages. If you want large number of pages then you map all requests to a single handler and then the handler works out what to  to return for a given request.